# Kotlin's safe-cast (or in this context "unsafe"-cast) hides possible NullPointerException warning by Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, ide

While developing in AS with Java, below line shows warning that `toggleSoftInput` may produce NPE. Which is quite helpful if you forgot NPE check.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(....);
```

But in the case of Kotlin, this becomes a problem. Casting with `as` means IDE won't bother to check if `toggleSoftInput()` may produce NPE or not because `as` implicitly implies so.

```
val imm = mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
imm.toggleSoftInput()
```

Once I use safe-cast `as?`, IDE warns me to make safe-call to `imm` as it may be `null`.

**General Question:** What if developer forgets to safe-cast, isn't Kotlin's safe-cast implicitly killing off IDE user-friendly capabilities or I'm missing out something?

**Specific Question:** Is there any possible way to resolve those issues other than not forgetting safe-cast? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly this specific method:

```
context.getSystemService(@NonNull String name)
```

is very old API and that's one of it's flaws - it returns an `Object` of unspecified type and nullability so there's no other way but performing unsafe/safe casting.

You have few newer alternatives that will give you safe nullable Service class objects:

```
// available since API 23:
val ims23 = context.getSystemService(InputMethodManager::class.java)

// available in androidx.core
val imsCompat = ContextCompat.getSystemService(context, InputMethodManager::class.java)

// available in androidx.core:core-ktx
val imsKtx = context.getSystemService<InputMethodManager>()
```

Comment: Basically, once on Kotlin, one should upgrade to AndroidX.